# Put data in a particularly shaped list

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list that looks like this:

```
my_list = [[20, 15, 10], [15, 22, 37, 46], [22, 91]]
```

So it is two dimensional, but not every line has the same number of elements.

I now have a flat ndarray, like:

```
my_ndarray = np.array([9, 2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 17])
```

That have the same amount of elements with my_list. Now I would like to shape my_ndarray to be the same with my_list, i.e.:

```
my_ndarray = [[9, 2, 4], [4, 1, 6, 7], [8, 17]]
```

So we can note that, both my_list and my_ndarray contain 3 sublists, and 1st sublist contains 3 elements, 2nd sublists has 4, and 3rd has 2 elements in it.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's crude but what about putting `inf` or `0` to make all the rows the same length? Also what do you mean by `the same with my list`? Also you can't really change the length of an existing array, need to create a new one.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Thanks for asking! I should've been clearer. I will edit my original post now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> it = iter([9, 2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 17])
>>> my_list = [[20, 15, 10], [15, 22, 37, 46], [22, 91]]
>>> [[next(it) for i in j] for j in my_list]
[[9, 2, 4], [4, 1, 6, 7], [8, 17]]
```

Comment: The "create an iterator and then walk another datastructure, calling next(it)" pattern is very useful when aligning data.  I don't know why it's not more popular.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`numpy.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = [[20, 15, 10], [15, 22, 37, 46], [22, 91]]
>>> my_ndarray = np.array([9, 2, 4, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 17])
>>> break_points = np.cumsum(map(len, my_list))
>>> break_points
array([3, 7, 9])
```

This returns list of arrays, slicing the `my_ndarray` at `[0:3]`, `[3:7]`, `[7:9]`, `[9:]`:

```
>>> np.array_split(my_ndarray, break_points)[:-1]
[array([9, 2, 4]), array([4, 1, 6, 7]), array([ 8, 17])]
```

To get a list of lists:

```
>>> map(list, np.array_split(my_ndarray, break_points)[:-1])
[[9, 2, 4], [4, 1, 6, 7], [8, 17]]
```