# sort a matrix using its value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example I have a matrix

```
a = [[6,8,9],[7,4,3],[1,2,5]]
```

now I want to sort matrix like as below

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

please help me I am new to python.

Comment: If you're new then through some [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) first and try something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For list-of-list, you can clone the shape like this

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [[6,8,9],[7,4,3],[1,2,5]]
>>> it = iter(sorted(chain.from_iterable(a)))
>>> [[next(it) for j in i] for i in a]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I was about to comment on how handy this pattern is when it sounded familiar -- several years ago I commented on [exactly the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227867/put-data-in-a-particularly-shaped-list#comment30166294_20227981), on *another* one of your answers!

Comment: @DSM, If people don't use these patterns - the alternatives are often rather convoluted

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> a = [[6,8,9],[7,4,3],[1,2,5]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = sorted(chain.from_iterable(a))
>>> [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l),3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```